# I'm failing to understand how the stack works

Tags: stack, 6502

I'm building an emulator for the MOS6502 processor, and at the moment I'm trying to simulate the stack in code, but I'm really failing to understand how the stack works in the context of the 6502.

One of the features of the 6502's stack structure is that when the stack pointer reaches the end of the stack it will wrap around, but I don't get how this feature even works.

Let's say we have a stack with 64 maximum values if we push the values `x`, `y` and `z` onto the stack, we now have the below structure. With the stack pointer pointing at address `0x62`, because that was the last value pushed onto the stack.

```
+-------+
|   x   | 0x64
+-------+
|   y   | 0x63
+-------+
|   z   | 0x62 <-SP
+-------+
|       | ...
+-------+
```

All well and good. But now if we pop those three values off the stack we now have an empty stack, with the stack pointer pointing at value `0x64`

```
+-------+
|       | 0x64 <-SP
+-------+
|       | 0x63
+-------+
|       | 0x62
+-------+
|       | ...
+-------+
```

If we pop the stack a fourth time, the stack pointer wraps around to point at address `0x00`, but what's even the point of doing this when there isn't a value at `0x00`?? There's nothing in the stack, so what's the point in wrapping the stack pointer around????

I can understand this process when pushing values, if the stack is full and a value needs to be pushed to the stack it'll overwrite the oldest value present on the stack. This doesn't work for popping.

Can someone please explain this because it makes no sense.

Comment: This is good.  I'm not sure what documented behavior is, but I'd expect it to just wrap around for consistency's sake. Of course a program that pops an empty stack has other issues.

Comment: There is ALWAYS a value at every memory address.

Comment: @jasonharper Does the stack pointer point to the last value that has been pushed to the stack OR the NEXT address that gets filled by a push operation?

Comment: S points to the next storage location. Eg PHA, [0x0100+S] = A, then S = S - 1. For PLA, S = S + 1, then A = [0x0100+S]. Example [here](https://wiki.nesdev.com/w/index.php/Stack).

Comment: Note that the stack can also be accessed by the program by simply referencing addresses in the `$0100`...`$01FF` range, including changing it; so you will set yourself up for all kinds of incoherence problems if you try to maintain a structured stack in your emulator beside the 'real' one in your (emulated) RAM.

Comment: It's an 8-bit register. When it wraps around to the first value, it points the top of the stack, because the high byte of the address is inferred and constant. It's just cycling through 256 addresses.

Answer (score 7):

> If we pop the stack a fourth time, the stack pointer wraps around to point at address 0x00, but what's even the point of doing this when there isn't a value at 0x00?? There's nothing in the stack, so what's the point in wrapping the stack pointer around????

It is not done for a functional reason.  The 6502 architecture was designed so that pushing and popping could be done by incrementing an 8 bit SP register without any additional checking.  Checks for overflow or underflow of the SP register would involve more silicon to implement them, more silicon to implement the stack overflow / underflow handling ... and extra gate delays in a critical path.

The 6502 was designed to be cheap and simple using 1975 era chip technology<sup>1</sup>.  Not fast.  Not sophisticated. Not easy to program<sup>2</sup>

---

<sup>1 - According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MOS_Technology_6502), the original design had ~3200 or ~3500 transistors.  One of the selling points of the 6502 was that it was cheaper than its competitors.  Fewer transistors meant smaller dies, better yields and lower production costs.

2 - Of course, this is relative.  Compared to some ISAs, the 6502 is easy because it is simple and orthogonal, and you have so few options to chose from.  But compared to others, the limitations that make it simple actually make it difficult.  For example, the fact that there are at most 256 bytes in the stack page that have to be shared by everything.  It gets awkward if you are implementing threads or coroutines. Compare this with an ISA where the SP is a 16 bit register or the stack can be anywhere.</sup>

Comment: It's actually pretty easy to program.  But easy to make a mistake :)

Comment: That's the point.  Easy to program provided you don't make mistakes == not easy to program :-)

Comment: I see.  I was thinking it was easy because it's a pretty easy instruction set and addressing mode scheme to get a handle on.  Compared to, say, x86 which always twisted my head around.

Comment: I think it is quite easy to program, certainly compared to a Z80 precisely because the options are very limited.

Comment: But Z80 had all those sweet 16-bit indexed instructions though.  They took like 50 clock cycles but they were pretty neat.